# How to combine 2 channel images with macro code in imageJ .

Tags: merge, composite, imagej

I tried to merge the red and the green channel images to generate a composite image. My code reads like :

```
          path = getDirectory("Choose a Directory"); 
          filename = getFileList(path); 

          newDir = path + "Single_Channel" + File.separator; 
          File.makeDirectory(newDir);   

         for (i=0; i<filename.length; i++)
         { 
         if(endsWith(filename[i], ".tif"))
         { 
          open(path+filename[i]); 
          filenameG = filename[i]+" (green)"; 
          filenameR = filename[i+1]+" (red)"; 
          run("Merge Channels...","c1=[" + filenameR + "] c2=[" +      filenameG + "] create"); 
            rename(filename[i]+"_composite"); 
            saveAs("tiff", newDir+getTitle); 
            close();
            }
            }
```

The error am getting is : The file ".........." is not for channel C1 (red). 
Because of this am unable to proceed to further processing of my image.

Any feedback is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: How is Merge Channels supposed to work with arguments which are just strings you created ? At the time you execute this line, the only opened image is "path+filename[i]" right ? There are no images "filenameR" or "G" opened right ? So how do you expect Merge Channels to work ?

Comment: Ok i think i found my mistake... thank you Soltius.